# CRM 2011: ExecuteMultipleRequest Freezing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The scenario I have is that I have a plugin which needs to run a whole bunch of **AddMembersTeamRequest** and **RemoveMembersTeamRequest** (around 2000 of each)

I am having trouble with the following code:

```cs
var executeMultipleRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest();
executeMultipleRequest.Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings() { ContinueOnError = false, ReturnResponses = false };

var organizationRequestCollection = new OrganizationRequestCollection();

foreach (var sharedRecordsOwningTeam in sharedRecordsOwningTeams)
{
    organizationRequestCollection.Add(CreateAddMembersTeamRequest(userId, sharedRecordsOwningTeam.Id));
}

executeMultipleRequest.Requests = organizationRequestCollection;
service.Execute(executeMultipleRequest);
```

However it doesn't matter how many requests are part of that **ExecuteMultipleRequest** as it just seems to freeze the process (I have tried having just **one** request in the **ExecuteMultipleRequest** collection)

But the following code seems to work fine:

```cs
foreach (var sharedRecordsOwningTeam in sharedRecordsOwningTeams)
{
    service.Execute(CreateAddMembersTeamRequest(userId, sharedRecordsOwningTeam.Id));
}
```

As you can see, the problem with my code above is that it causes the process to execute around 2000+ requests.

Would anyone know why using the **ExecuteMultipleRequest** freezes the process entirely? (Even when there is only 1 add/remove team member request in the request collection)

Comment: We're on CRM rollup 14

Comment: When you enable logging (http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/), do you see any errors?

Comment: try adding preferreddc. See here: http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2010/11/crm-performance-and-setting-preferreddc-registry-key.html

Comment: have you tried looking at sql server trace to see if anything is being exectued while it freezes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I think it was freezing on me because I was trying to remove a user from the default team of their current Business Unit.

For some reason the request wasn't erroring and instead just sat there.

However I think I should also point out that using an **ExecuteMultipleRequest** wasn't any faster than running multiple **AddMembersTeamRequest.**

Even a giant **AssociateRequest** wasn't any faster.